# Retire Constable Badge

Tags: discussion, badges

The Constable badge : Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation

and is rewarded for such, however, since this badge cannot be awarded, 
should it not be retired!?

Comment: It can be awarded at other sites, so removing it seems a bit drastic? SO isn't the only site in the SE network.

Comment: The Constable badge has never been awarded.

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/badges/85/constable,
https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/207/constable
I could go on but it seems pointless. It has not never been rewarded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The badge system is a Stack Exchange network wide feature. The feature is not tuned / configurable per site.

Badges are used to reward positive behavior. Having served as a pro-tem moderator is worth recognition, especially in cases where the pro-tem doesn't come out as a winner during the first moderator election.

Stack Overflow never had pro-tem moderators. They went from SE staff moderating to elected moderators. Hence the badge is not awarded here.

Retiring a badge needs to be done network-wide. The badge is useful and is still awarded on other sites in the SE network. The badge should stay.